# MPAndroidChart is not responding to setViewPortOffsets(...) until redrawn

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I'm trying to add some interior left and right padding to a LineChart from mpandroidchart. setViewPortOffsets(10 ,0, 10, 0) does not seem to affect the chart until it has been redrawn at least once.

Per https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport I'm calling this method after setting the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling

`chart.notifyDataChanged()`

and

`chart.invalidate()`

After setting the offsets.